# How do I update the score in sprite kit when a node passes a certain y coordinate on the screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my sprite kit game, a point is scored when a node moves past another node. I tried to code this mechanic so that when the y-coordinate of the obstacle node is greater than the y coordinate of the player node, a point is scored. However, this does not work. This code one works when the greater than sign is changed to a less than sign, and the score is updated as soon as the obstacles appear on the screen. I only want the score to update when the obstacle pass the player. Any help will be appreciated, thanks

```
    if (obstacle1.position.y > person1.position.y) {
    scoreNumber++;
    scoreLabelNode.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", scoreNumber];
    }
```

Comment: you need a clear physics body that registers a "collision" when it first touches the player. Add this as a child of the obstacle and increment score in physics handler

Comment: this has been done for the game over method. I just want the score updated with the obstacle passes by without collision. thanks for your help

Comment: Your `if` statement will be `true` when `obstacle1` is closer to the top of the scene than `person1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your player is at the bottom of the screen and the obstacle starts at the top, the correct if statement should read:

```
if (obstacle1.position.y < person1.position.y)
```

If however your player is at the top and the obstacle starts at the bottom, the correct if statement is:

```
if (obstacle1.position.y > person1.position.y)
```

You will have to include some BOOL property for the obstacles in order not to have your score increased over and over again for the same obstacle. Another option is to have all your obstacles in an array (for purposes of scoring) and remove any obstacle from the array once it passes the player.